# Compile error: storage size of 'arr' isn't constant

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, static

I have a problem in this code.
This gives:

```
storage size of 'arr' isn't constant
  int static arr[size];"
```

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int* func( int size );
void main (){
    int*res ;
    int len =5 ;
    res=func(len);
    for(int i=0 ;i<len;++i){
        printf("The Element %d is \n",i,*(res+i));
    }
}
int* func( int size ){
    
    int static arr[size];
    for(int i=0 ;i<size;++i){
        printf("Enter %d \n",i);
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    return arr ;
}
```

Why?  How can I fix it?

Comment: Advice: Whenever you have an error just paste it directly into your favourite search engine. Most of the time the top hit will give you an answer. Doing basic research is often faster than posting on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Note that specifying the storage class (`static`, `extern`) other than first in a declaration or definition is an obsolescent feature — see [§6.11.5 Storage class specifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.11.5) — _The placement of a storage-class specifier other than at the beginning of the declaration specifiers in a declaration is an obsolescent feature_ — (and [§6.7.1 Storage class specifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.1)).

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare a variable-length array as `static`.

Objects with static storage duration are allocated when the program is first loaded; `arr` will be allocated before `func` is ever called.  For this to work, `arr`'s size has to be known at compile time.

Unfortunately, you using the parameter `size` when you declare the array, whose size isn't known until runtime; this makes it a variable-length array.

So, this isn't going to work the way you want - you'll probably want to use the `malloc` or `calloc` library functions instead.